# Крашится бот если ввожу неправильно город Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

пишу погодного бота, если вводят любое слово кроме города, он крашится, как это исправить, помогите пожалуйста

```
import pyowm 
import telebot

owm = pyowm.OWM('b73122e8768816f7169ad291c7adda8a', language = "ru")
bot = telebot.TeleBot("946873330:AAHO73g_QoTjZtfZO6na2ri_4F7KhZmWC2M")

@bot.message_handler(commands=["start", "help"])
def start(message):
    if message.text == '/start':
         bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Привет, я покажу вам погоду, укажите ваш город:")
         bot.register_next_step_handler(message, send_echo)
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def send_echo(message):
    observation = owm.weather_at_place( message.text )
    w = observation.get_weather()
    temp = w.get_temperature('celsius') ["temp"]
    answer =  " В городе " + message.text + " сейчас " + w.get_detailed_status()  + "\n" 
    answer +=  "Температура  в районе " + str(temp) + " °C " + "\n\n"
    if temp < 10:
        answer +=  "Сейчас холодно, одевайтесь теплее."
    elif temp <20:
        answer += "Можно увидеть людей в шубе и сланцах."
    else:
        answer += "Температура хорошая, одейвайся как хочешь."



    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,answer)


bot.polling( none_stop = True)
```

Comment: Используйте конструкцию `try-except`.

Comment: Подозреваю, что после observation = owm.weather_at_place( message.text ) надо бы проверить какой ответ пришел! Если там пусто (не найден такой город) то смысл вызывать у пустого ответа запрос температуры? Там и падает скорее всего.